# Styling a vertical-line

Tags: html, css

I want to make a vertical line looking like this:

http://i41.tinypic.com/2na44n7.png

I've tried the following code:

```
div.vertical-line{
    float:right;
    width:5px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-right:20px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#CFCFCF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF);
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF);
    behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

but the result wasn't as expected.
here is the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/rLyyc/

it's close, but it doesn't "fade-out" at the end of the line.

Any suggestions?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks fine to me (firefox on linux)

Comment: Fades out fine if your background is white.  That said...  Instead of using HEX codes for your colors, switch over to RGBA.  The A stands for alpha, which means you can set a transparency on the color.  Anything between 0 and 1 can be used for the alpha value.  0 means completely transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), I got this for you:

```
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #c6cbd2 50%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(50%,#c6cbd2), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#c6cbd2 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#c6cbd2 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#c6cbd2 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#c6cbd2 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: Bingo! much appriciated!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add another stop point, i.e.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#CFCFCF), to(#FFFFFF));
```

Resulting in:

```
div.vertical-line{
    float:right;
    width:5px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-right:20px;
    min-height: 550px;
    height:100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#CFCFCF), to(#FFFFFF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF, #FFFFFF);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF, #FFFFFF);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF, #FFFFFF);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF, #FFFFFF);
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF, #FFFFFF);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #CFCFCF, #FFFFFF);
    behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

It's worth looking at MDN to see how color-stops work in linear-gradient: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 0):

This will create the line that your looking for and position it in the middle of the page.  Just adjust the width for line-thickness, height for height of the line from top to bottom, top for how far down before the line starts, and colors to whatever you want them to be.

```
body:after { 
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:50%;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    border: 0;
    height: 80%;
    width:1px;
    background: #333;
    background-image: 
        -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
    }
```